# Java Shoutcast Query

Tags: java, irc, bots, shoutcast

I have a Java IRC bot which i would like to query a shoutcast server and return basic information (song playing etc). Can someone guide me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Get Cidero Java source code from here,

http://www.cidero.com/downloads.html

Inside the ZIP file, you will find a class ShoutcastSnooper, which is a good example that show you how to parse meta data.